# Rails table join with extra details doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have these 2 models, and I'm trying to add an association between them so I can add some extra details later:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :event_tickets
  has_many :events, :through => :event_tickets
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :event_tickets
  has_many :tickets, :through => :event_tickets
end

class EventTicket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :ticket
end
```

I've tried adding an association like this, just to see it's working:

```
event_ticket = EventTicket.new(:ticket => ticket, :event => Event.all[0])
event_ticket.save!
```

This gives me:

```
can't write unknown attribute `ticket_id`
```

The ticket and event exist and are working fine, but can't get the event_ticket object working.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have an `event_tickets` table, or at least it doesn't have a `ticket_id` column. Are you sure you wrote the migration and ran it?

Comment: That was it, forgot the ticket_id in the migration.